# jQuery one button hide show edited/new content

Tags: jquery

I have an html content which is modified by a 3'rd party tool.

The html contains the changed/deleted text as well as the new one.

Example:

[image]

The html code is like this:

```
<p class="ct_new">This is the new html content</p>
<p class="ct_changed">This is the old html content</p>
```

Now I need to implement a button that will show/hide the changes.

- By default the new content is shown and the edited/changed/deleted one is hidden.
- When user clicks the show/hide button the edited/changed/deleted is shown, red color and strikethrough. The new text color is green.
- When user clicks the show/hide button again the edited/changed/deleted is hidden and the new text color is black.

Here is my approach: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2n4m1jv/)

HTML:

```js
$('.ct-new').addClass('h-changes-new');
$('.ct_changed').addClass('h-changes');

$('#showChanges').click(function() {
  $('.ct_new').toggleClass('h-changes-new s-changes-new');
  $('.ct_changed').toggleClass('s-changes h-changes');
});
```

```css
.s-changes {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  display: block;
}
.h-changes {
  color: #000000;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}
.s-changes-new {
  color: #347C2C;
}
.h-changes-new {
  color: #000000;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="showChanges" title="Show/Hide Changes">
  Show/Hide
</button>

<p class="ct_new">This is the new html content</p>
<p class="ct_changed">This is the old html content</p>
```

I cannot make the text green for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jfLb3nd/1/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a CSS priority issue in selector. The black color overrides the green color rules. You need to provide a more specific selector for the green color

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z2n4m1jv/1/

```
p.s-changes-new {
    color: #347C2C;
}
```

Just added a `p` in the rules which makes it more specific and hence more priority

**Note:** You may use `!important` to override the rules. But I strongly advise you not to use it. This should be your last option

Comment: @user2818430 Yeah. Sometimes you just need to look at the browser console for clues

Comment: Yes I must agree, `!important` can lead to problems which are not easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the `s-changes-new` class does not overwrite the `color` property of `h-changes-new`, where it is set to black.

You can enforce the color by setting the value to `!important`:

```
.s-changes-new {
    color: #347C2C !important;        
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oo8np8p3/